# Using CTE and aggregate functions with UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression, postgresql-10

In PostgreSQL 10.6 I am trying to store results of 2 aggregate function calls into the `avg_score` and `avg_time` columns of the `words_users` table, but unfortunately get the syntax error:

```
WITH last_week_moves AS (
    SELECT
            m.gid,
            m.uid,
            m.played - LAG(m.played) OVER(PARTITION BY m.gid ORDER BY played) AS diff
    FROM words_moves m
    JOIN words_games g ON (m.gid = g.gid AND 5 IN (g.player1, g.player2))
    WHERE m.played > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 week'
)
UPDATE words_users SET
        avg_score = (SELECT ROUND(AVG(score), 1) FROM words_moves WHERE uid = 5),
        avg_time = TO_CHAR(AVG(diff), 'HH24:MI')
FROM last_week_moves
WHERE uid = 5
GROUP BY uid;
```

(I am using the hardcoded `uid = 5` in the above statement, but in the real life the latter is wrapped inside of a PL/PgSQL stored function and is using a parameter `uid = in_uid`).

```
ERROR:  42601: syntax error at or near "GROUP"
LINE 15: GROUP BY uid
         ^
LOCATION:  scanner_yyerror, scan.l:1128
```

The database seems to be unhappy with the `GROUP BY`, but I need it for `AVG(diff)`, because the CTE delivers the times between moves always for 2 players in a game:

```
SELECT
        m.gid,
        m.uid,
        m.played - LAG(m.played) OVER(PARTITION BY m.gid ORDER BY played) AS diff
FROM words_moves m
JOIN words_games g ON (m.gid = g.gid AND 5 IN (g.player1, g.player2))
WHERE m.played > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 week';

  gid  |  uid  |         diff
-------+-------+-----------------------
 50399 |   774 | ¤
 50608 |  8977 | ¤
 50608 |     5 | 00:39:48.121149
 50608 |  8977 | 00:09:46.221235
 50608 |     5 | 01:35:23.524209
 50608 |  8977 | 09:26:40.794061
 50697 |     5 | ¤
 50697 | 10322 | 02:13:16.502079
 50697 |     5 | 01:47:44.681788
 50697 | 10322 | 00:01:31.597973
 50697 |     5 | 12:11:24.54716
 50697 | 10322 | 12:01:15.078243
 50697 |     5 | 11:52:39.60056
 50697 | 10322 | 00:11:30.491137
 50697 |     5 | 00:14:53.612513
 50697 | 10322 | 01:45:23.940957
 ...
 52469 |     5 | 02:46:29.768655
 52469 |  8550 | 01:16:45.169882
 52469 |     5 | 08:38:00.691552
(59 rows)
```

Does anybody please know, how to change my `UPDATE` query?

Below are the 3 tables in question:

```
 # \d words_users
                                         Table "public.words_users"
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                 Default
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 uid           | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('words_users_uid_seq'::regclass)
 created       | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 visited       | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 ip            | inet                     |           | not null |
 fcm           | text                     |           |          |
 apns          | text                     |           |          |
 adm           | text                     |           |          |
 motto         | text                     |           |          |
 vip_until     | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 grand_until   | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 banned_until  | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 banned_reason | text                     |           |          |
 elo           | integer                  |           | not null |
 medals        | integer                  |           | not null |
 coins         | integer                  |           | not null |
 avg_score     | double precision         |           |          |
 avg_time      | text                     |           |          |
Indexes:
    "words_users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uid)
Check constraints:
    "words_users_banned_reason_check" CHECK (length(banned_reason) > 0)
    "words_users_elo_check" CHECK (elo >= 0)
    "words_users_medals_check" CHECK (medals >= 0)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "words_chat" CONSTRAINT "words_chat_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_games" CONSTRAINT "words_games_player1_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (player1) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_games" CONSTRAINT "words_games_player2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (player2) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_moves" CONSTRAINT "words_moves_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_reviews" CONSTRAINT "words_reviews_author_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_reviews" CONSTRAINT "words_reviews_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_scores" CONSTRAINT "words_scores_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_social" CONSTRAINT "words_social_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_stats" CONSTRAINT "words_stats_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE

# \d words_moves
                                      Table "public.words_moves"
 Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                 Default
---------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 mid     | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('words_moves_mid_seq'::regclass)
 action  | text                     |           | not null |
 gid     | integer                  |           | not null |
 uid     | integer                  |           | not null |
 played  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 tiles   | jsonb                    |           |          |
 score   | integer                  |           |          |
 letters | text                     |           |          |
 hand    | text                     |           |          |
 puzzle  | boolean                  |           | not null | false
Indexes:
    "words_moves_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (mid)
    "words_moves_gid_played_idx" btree (gid, played DESC)
    "words_moves_uid_idx" btree (uid)
Check constraints:
    "words_moves_score_check" CHECK (score >= 0)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "words_moves_gid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES words_games(gid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "words_moves_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "words_scores" CONSTRAINT "words_scores_mid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES words_moves(mid) ON DELETE CASCADE

# \d words_games
                                      Table "public.words_games"
  Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                 Default
----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 gid      | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('words_games_gid_seq'::regclass)
 created  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 finished | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 player1  | integer                  |           | not null |
 player2  | integer                  |           |          |
 played1  | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 played2  | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 state1   | text                     |           |          |
 state2   | text                     |           |          |
 reason   | text                     |           |          |
 hint1    | text                     |           |          |
 hint2    | text                     |           |          |
 score1   | integer                  |           | not null |
 score2   | integer                  |           | not null |
 chat1    | integer                  |           | not null |
 chat2    | integer                  |           | not null |
 hand1    | character(1)[]           |           | not null |
 hand2    | character(1)[]           |           | not null |
 pile     | character(1)[]           |           | not null |
 letters  | character(1)[]           |           | not null |
 values   | integer[]                |           | not null |
 bid      | integer                  |           | not null |
 friendly | boolean                  |           |          |
Indexes:
    "words_games_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
    "words_games_player1_coalesce_idx" btree (player1, COALESCE(finished, 'infinity'::timestamp with time zone))
    "words_games_player2_coalesce_idx" btree (player2, COALESCE(finished, 'infinity'::timestamp with time zone))
Check constraints:
    "words_games_chat1_check" CHECK (chat1 >= 0)
    "words_games_chat2_check" CHECK (chat2 >= 0)
    "words_games_check" CHECK (player1 <> player2)
    "words_games_score1_check" CHECK (score1 >= 0)
    "words_games_score2_check" CHECK (score2 >= 0)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "words_games_bid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES words_boards(bid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "words_games_player1_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (player1) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "words_games_player2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (player2) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "words_chat" CONSTRAINT "words_chat_gid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES words_games(gid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_moves" CONSTRAINT "words_moves_gid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES words_games(gid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_scores" CONSTRAINT "words_scores_gid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES words_games(gid) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @lau I have tried moving the AVG into the CTE, but get another syntax error:

```
WITH last_week_moves AS (
                SELECT
                        m.gid,
                        m.uid,
                        TO_CHAR(AVG(m.played - LAG(m.played) OVER(PARTITION BY m.gid ORDER BY played)), 'HH24:MI') AS diff
                FROM words_moves m
                JOIN words_games g ON (m.gid = g.gid AND 5 IN (g.player1, g.player2))
                WHERE m.played > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 week'
                GROUP BY uid
)
UPDATE words_users SET
        avg_score = (SELECT ROUND(AVG(score), 1) FROM words_moves WHERE uid = 5),
        avg_time = diff
FROM last_week_moves
WHERE uid = 5;

ERROR:  42803: aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls
LINE 5:                         TO_CHAR(AVG(m.played - LAG(m.played)...
                                                       ^
LOCATION:  check_agg_arguments_walker, parse_agg.c:728
```

Comment: Not sure about the syntax but since uid is in the WHERE, you do not need the group by at least.

Comment: `group by` is invalid in an `UPDATE` statement

Comment: How to feed an `UPDATE` with `AVG` results then?

Comment: why not calculating the average in the CTE directly? `WITH last_week_moves AS (SELECT avg(diff), <other fields> FROM (<What you already typed>) UPDATE ...`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that produces another syntax error: *aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls* please see the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
WITH last_week_moves AS (
      SELECT m.uid,
             (MAX(m.played) - MIN(m.played)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0) as avg_diff,
             AVG(score) as avg_score
      FROM words_moves m JOIN
           words_games g
           ON m.gid = g.gid AND 5 IN (g.player1, g.player2)
      WHERE m.played > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 week'
      GROUP BY m.uid
     )
UPDATE words_users wu
    SET avg_score = lwm.avg_score,
        avg_time = TO_CHAR(avg_diff, 'HH24:MI')
FROM last_week_moves lwm
WHERE wu.uid = lwm.uid AND
      wu.uid = 5;
```

Note that this simplifies the calculate of the `diff` calculation, so `lag()` is not needed.

You can see that these are equivalent:
   value     diff
   1
   4         3
   9         5

The average of diff is obviously 4.  This is `((4 - 1) + (9 - 4)) / 2`.  You see that the "4"s cancel, so it is really `(9 - 1) / 2`.  This observation generalizes.

Comment: I am amazed how your code produces the same values as my `LAG`-using code... Could you explain the `(MAX(m.played) - MIN(m.played)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0)` trick, how does it work?